# Output of ArrayList from Java class into JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, javabeans

I have a JSP file inputs a string to a Java class, and should get an ArrayList returned from it. Do I need a public class (i.e. **void main(String[] args)** ) to be able to return to the calling JSP, or is **public Scopus()** enough to return the values?

Scopus.java (accepts in scopusID, returns scopusList)

```
package newpackage1;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.CharacterData;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class Scopus {

    String scopusID;
    URL url;
    ArrayList<String> scopusList = new ArrayList<String>();
    NodeList nodes;
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    Document doc;

    public void setScopusList(ArrayList scopusList) {
        this.scopusList = scopusList;
    }

    public ArrayList getScopusList() {
        return scopusList;
    }

    public void setScopusID(String url) {
        this.scopusID = url;
    }

    public String getScopusID() {
        return scopusID;
    }

    public Scopus(String scopusID) {

        String fTitle, fLink;

        try {
            URL url = new URL( "http://syndic8.scopus.com/getMessage?registrationId=" + scopusID );
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

        try {
            builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            doc = builder.parse(url.openStream());
            nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        //Only output if at least one is found
        int counter = 0;
        if ( nodes.getLength() > 0 ) {
            //Place all results into an array list first
            for(int i=0;i<nodes.getLength();i++) {
                Element element = (Element)nodes.item(i);
                fTitle = getElementValue(element, "title");
                fLink = getElementValue(element, "link");

                scopusList.add("<a href=\"" + fLink + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + fTitle + "</a>");

                counter++;
            }
         }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    }

    private String getElementValue(Element parent,String label) {
        return getCharacterDataFromElement((Element)parent.getElementsByTagName(label).item(0));
    }
    private String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
        try {
            Node child = e.getFirstChild();
            if(child instanceof CharacterData) {
                CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
                return cd.getData();
            } //if
        } //try
        catch(Exception ex) {

        }
        return " ";
    } //private String getCharacterDataFromElement
}
```

output.jsp (Calls the above class)

```
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList,org.w3c.dom.Node,org.w3c.dom.NodeList" %>

<%
   String feedID = "HEDCIHLCIGDKPFHHJEEEHJDEIEGJIKJHKWFQWLHFJH";
%>

<jsp:useBean id="scopus" scope="page" class="newpackage1.Scopus">
    <jsp:setProperty name="scopus" property="scopusID" value="<%= feedID %>" />
</jsp:useBean>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:getProperty name="scopus" property="scopusList" />

        <%

        ArrayList sl = scopus.getScopusList();
//Will do output later
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What servlet puts that list into request scope?  I don't see any such thing.

Comment: Ah, I am an idiot. Question will be posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The class you specify in class must not be abstract and must have a public, no-argument constructor** which you don't have.

**Update:**: You **don't** need main() method, a public Scopus() non-argument constructor will be fine. The JSP container will create an instance of this class using reflection using the zero-argument constructor. If you don't create any constructor, Java compiler will add one to the compiled class. You only need to rename your original constructor with parameter to make it a method to do all those business logic things and call it somewhere after you have set scopusID property and before the `getScopusList()` method is called (when you try to access the scopusList property).

As for the presentation of the list data, it is not a good idea to use:

```
<jsp:getProperty name="scopus" property="scopusList" />

<%
    ArrayList sl = scopus.getScopusList();
//Will do output later
%>
```

You better use JSP EL and JSTL core taglib and do something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${scopus.scopusList}" var="item">
    ${item}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I change `public Scopus(String scopusID)` to `public Scopus() {}`, and move all relevant code to **public static void main(String[] args)** ?

Comment: @AngrySpartan: no, that's not a good idea. the main() method won't be called. See the update of this post.

Comment: I removed the argument from `public Scopus()`. I no longer get the _"The value for the useBean class attribute XXXXX is invalid"_, so now it's purely code within the function that I get errors for. Thanks for your help on this small step.